# Upper Density of the Set of Points that can be Scored in American Football

Tags: number-theory

In American football, a team can score 2, 3, 6, 7, or 8 points at a time. If we let A be the set of all possible total scores that a team can manage to gain (in an infinitely long game of American football), what is the additive upper density of A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $2$ can be obtained, so too any even number. Any odd number that is at least $3$ can be written as $2k+3$ where $k$ is a nonnegative integer, so the only positive number that cannot be attained is 1.

Comment: Yeah, this was definitely a boring question.  But good answer!